# Regex for IP Pattern Check is returning false in Java

Tags: java, json, regex

I have been trying to check the IP pattern is present in Json or not using Java. However Pattern matcher is returning false. Below is my code snippet

```
String responseJsonData = "{\"ip\":127.0.0.1}";
or
String responseJsonData = "{\"127.0.0.1\":201}";

String ipPattern = "\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+";
boolean ipPatternRegex = rgxptrn.compileRegexPatternWithMatcher(ipPattern, responseJsonData);
System.out.println(ipPatternRegex);
Assert.assertFalse(ipPatternRegex, "JSON String Contains IP Patterns");
```

```
        
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regexPattern);
        Matcher match = pattern.matcher(jsonString);
        System.out.println("Pattern Result is : " + match.matches());
        return match.matches();
    }
```

Either responseDataInput is returning false.
how to brute force the search for IP Pattern match using regex.

Answer (score 2):

Your pattern is correct. The problem is that you are using [`Matcher#matches`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches()) instead of [`Matcher#find`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find()).

**Demo:**

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class EntryPoint {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+");
        
        Stream.of(
                    "{\"ip\":127.0.0.1}",
                    "{\"127.0.0.1\":201}",
                    "{\"127.a.0.1\":201}"
                ).forEach(s -> System.out.println(s + " => " + pattern.matcher(s).find()));
    }   
}
```

**Output:**

```
{"ip":127.0.0.1} => true
{"127.0.0.1":201} => true
{"127.a.0.1":201} => false
```